# how to implement a listener on specific items using ListVIew?

Tags: android

I created a ListView with bunch of items, but I am not actually sure how to implement a listener on a specific items. Please help me! I would realy applreacte it a lot.

I tried to use this code, but when I click on any items, it will only bring me to the same Activity.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id)                               
   {
      Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
      startActivity(i);                                                                                                                                                                                   
   }
});
```

But if I use this code with if statement, nothing is happening:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{                                                                                                                                                             
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id)                               
      {                                                                                                                                                                           
         if(list.getItemAtPosition(position).equals(mStrings[0]))                                                       
         {                                                                                                           
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);                                                                                        
            startActivity(i);                                                                                
         }                                                                                                    
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could base your condition on `position` itself:

```
if (position == 0) {
    ... start activity ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm! You really save my arse, I have been struggling for days to figure that out, and in this little code you have saved my life. I have lived lol

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set different listeners in the getView method of the adapter>